# Swift and SpriteKit : I am not able to create an SKPhysicsJoint

Tags: sprite-kit, swift

With [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/) and [Sprite Kit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html), I want to create an SKPhysicsJoint (for example [an SKPhysicsJointFixed](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsJointFixed_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsJointFixed/jointWithBodyA:bodyB:anchor:)) but the problem is that Xcode doesn't suggest me anything :
[image]
And if I try to set what should be settled *(bodyA, bodyB, anchor)* manually, I can do this :

```
myJoint.bodyA = ...
myJoint.bodyB = ...
```

But **I can't set the anchor point this way**... It looks like it should be set with the initialization method but **I simply don't get how to do that**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
let joint = SKPhysicsJointFixed.jointWithBodyA(node1.physicsBody, bodyB:node2.physicsBody, anchorA:nodea.position, anchorB:node2.position)
self.physicsWorld.addJoint(joint)
```

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 3 the answer would be:

```
let fixedJoint = SKPhysicsJointFixed.joint(withBodyA: nodeA.physicsBody!, bodyB: nodeB.physicsBody!, anchor: anchorPoint)
self.physicsWorld.add(joint)
```

Assuming both physics bodies are set up.

Comment: where should the anchor be??